# docs api documentId from classroom

Tags: google-docs-api, google-classroom

I am trying to read google classroom classwork link slide document. It is returning 404 as I am not able to retrieve the documentId.
Scenario: Teacher creates the slide in google docs and publish that to web. Before publishing, it will have a different documentId in the url , after publishing to web, the url changes completely. No idea, what happens to the original documentId.

Question: How do we get documentId from the published to web document?
If I am logging in as student, can I actually retrieve documentId using google docs api documents.list or get?
Which api can be used to access the document link under Google Classroom > Announcements and >Classwork

Answer (score 0):

The Slide document remains unchanged when it's published to the web. You won't be able to get the Id as this feature is meant to share the document with a lot of peope restricting the access to the source material.

Even if you could retrieve the file Id, it's probable that you don't have View permissions to the Slide.

More information about published files:
https://support.google.com/a/users/answer/9308870?hl=en